# Перебор словаря по значениям с выводом ключей

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции, словари, dict

Удалось отсортировать ключи по алфавиту и вывести на печать их и их соответствующие значения.

```
nickname = {
"Sven":"Svensson",
"Song":"Jat Seng",
"Leonid":"Chekalov",
"Andjey":"Sapkovsky",
"Sidhartkha":"Budda",
}

for N in sorted(nickname.keys()):
    print(N)
    print(nickname[N]+"\n")
```

вывод:

```
Andjey
Sapkovsky

Leonid
Chekalov

Sidhartkha
Budda

Song
Jat Seng

Sven
Svensson
```

Как выполнить обратную задачу: вывести на печать отсортированные значения И их соответствующие ключи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто составьте обратный словарь, поменяйте ключ и значение местами:

```
nick_by_name = {
    "Sven": "Svensson",
    "Song": "Jat Seng",
    "Leonid": "Chekalov",
    "Andjey": "Sapkovsky",
    "Sidhartkha": "Budda",
}

name_by_nick = {v: k for k, v in nick_by_name.items()}

for name in sorted(name_by_nick.keys()):
    nick = name_by_nick[name]
    print(name)
    print(nick + "\n")
```

Результат:

```
Budda
Sidhartkha

Chekalov
Leonid

Jat Seng
Song

Sapkovsky
Andjey

Svensson
Sven
```

Comment: То есть более элегантного способа без ввода другого словаря не существует?

Comment: @StepanSokol, более красивого способа не знаю, если бы знал, его бы описал :) А что вас в нем неустраивает?

Comment: нет, все хорошо работает, просто универсальная привычка обходиться как можно меньшим количеством объектов. 
Спасибо, ответ засчитан.

Answer (score 5):

Альтернативное решение (без использования явных дополнительных объектов):

```
from operator import itemgetter

print('\n\n'.join(['{0[1]}\n{0[0]}'.format(tup)
                   for tup in sorted(nickname.items(), key=itemgetter(1))]))
```

Результат:

```
Budda
Sidhartkha

Chekalov
Leonid

Jat Seng
Song

Sapkovsky
Andjey

Svensson
Sven
```

Пошагово:

сортировка вернет отсортированный по значениям список кортежей:

```
In [5]: sorted(nickname.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
Out[5]:
[('Sidhartkha', 'Budda'),
 ('Leonid', 'Chekalov'),
 ('Song', 'Jat Seng'),
 ('Andjey', 'Sapkovsky'),
 ('Sven', 'Svensson')]
```

вернем список строк,где вначале идет значение, перевод строки и ключ:

```
In [6]: ['{0[1]}\n{0[0]}'.format(tup)
   ...:  for tup in sorted(nickname.items(), key=itemgetter(1))]
   ...:
Out[6]:
['Budda\nSidhartkha',
 'Chekalov\nLeonid',
 'Jat Seng\nSong',
 'Sapkovsky\nAndjey',
 'Svensson\nSven']
```

теперь объединим все элементы списка из предыдущего шага в одну строку, используя два перевода строки в качестве разделителя:

```
In [7]: '\n\n'.join(['{0[1]}\n{0[0]}'.format(tup)
   ...:                    for tup in sorted(nickname.items(), key=itemgetter(1))])
   ...:
Out[7]: 'Budda\nSidhartkha\n\nChekalov\nLeonid\n\nJat Seng\nSong\n\nSapkovsky\nAndjey\n\nSvensson\nSven'
```

при выводе этой строки на печать получится результат представленный выше

Comment: спасибо! я недавно начал изучать Python, можно прокомментировать код?

Comment: @StepanSokol, добавил пошаговые пояснения...

Comment: Я правильно понял, что в процессе кода словарь распадается и на выводе у нас один объект строки?

Comment: @StepanSokol, да в итоге мы получаем одну строку - это видно в выводе `Out[7]:`